# Linux: alter LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime

Tags: linux, dynamic, load

I'm working on a simple plugin architecture for my app. A plugin is a shared object with a known "get interface" function. I access the .so via dlopen/dlsym etc. Fairly standard. 
Some of my plugins have extra .so files that need to be loaded too. These files can be shipped with a plugin fine, but I need the app to know where/how to load them.

So my question is: how to I add a particular plugin's directory to the list of places to look for libraries? I can't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting the app, as the plugin will be loaded some time later. Alternatively, do I need each plugin to explicitly provide the list of dependencies in some kind of manifest file, so that I may load them with dlopen() first? Thanks.

Edit: to clarify, the plugins' directories are not known prior to starting the app, so I cannot set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH at that time.

Comment: You can and should link your plugins `*.so` file with the required shared libraries `gcc -Wall -O -shared -fPIC plugin.c -lsomelibrary -o plugin.so`

Comment: I am doing that already, but the issue arises at runtime with the app environment not knowing where libsomelibrary.so lives - that's the thing I need to be able to specify after the app has started.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-change-add-to-library-search-path-at-runtime-on-linux-855278/) linux evaluates LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting the app, so it is unaware of any changes you make at runtime.